# Browser bug/misunderstanding? `::first-letter` matches whole text in some cases

Tags: html, css, browser

I noticed that some text appeared much bigger and in different color than anticipated.
The browser inspector didn't show any `font-size` specific (computed) style for that element.
Even adding `font-size` as an inline style had no effect whatsoever.
After reducing the markup and styles to obtain a minimal reproducible page,
I noticed that a selector for an element above the affected element was responsible:

```css
p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

But not only the first letter, also the whole text was selected and styled.
This only seems to happen with a particular DOM and text structure:

```html
<p>
  <em>*
    Test
  </em>
</p>
```

The `<p>` element with the `<em>` element above, containing some specific characters as `*`; `#` and `!` and a subsequent space character triggers this behavior.

But this issue appears in all major browsers: Chrome; Edge; Opera, but also Firefox Stable and Firefox Developer Edition which use different engines.
Only the legacy Internet Explorer 11 that doesn't yet use the Chromium engine shows it correct, with only the first letter being selected and styles.
Because of this consistent behavior in all major, well-behaving browsers I doubt that this is really a browser bug but maybe rather a special quirk or interpretation of the specifications.

How can this be explained? Is the specific character somehow invalid or do the specs treat the whole text as the first character if the text starts with a specific character and subsequent space character?
Or is this indeed a bug across all the browsers/engines?

Minimal, reproducible case:

```css
p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <em>* Test</em>
</p>
```

On CodePen:
https://codepen.io/strarsis/pen/NWagxro
On CodePen, Live view (for older browsers that are deprecated on CodePen):
https://codepen.io/strarsis/full/NWagxro

Edit: When the inner element (`<em>`) is made a non-inline element (e.g. by applying `display: inline-block;`), the selector correctly applies only on the first character.
The browser treats the whole inline `<em>` element as the first letter.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 95 on Ubuntu, and for me none of the text is red: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tlNF.png